# How big would a MySQL database be if I save all webpages' title and URL in it?

Tags: mysql, web-crawler

For learning purposes, I want to make a simple web indexer which crawls the web and saves all found pages in a MySQL database with their titles and URLs, with this table (the page's content is not saved):

- id: integer AUTO_INCREMENT PRI
- title: varchar(100)
- url: varchar(500)

How big would that database be approximately? Is it about hundreds of MB, GB or around TBs? Thanks.

Comment: None of us knows, or can possibly know, how many web sites there are. Long before you discover even a tiny percentage the situation will have changed dramatically.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the quick and dirty answer, scroll the bottom. Otherwise, read through my narrative to understand how I came up with those numbers.

In 2008, Google released some numbers that might be of interest of you. At that time, Google's spiders were aware of over **1 trillion (that's 1,000,000,000,000) unique URLs**. One thing to take note of is that **not all of these URLs are indexed**.  For your case here, we'll pretend that we *are* going to index everything.
You can read this announcement here: http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2008/07/we-knew-web-was-big.html

The current size of your `id` column only allows for *2 billion* URLs in the index. If you make that an `unsigned int` you can squeeze *4 billion* out, but assuming a near-infinite scale you'd want to use an `unsigned bigint` In all reality, you'd want to use a uuid or something similar so you can generate IDs concurrently (and from multiple hosts,) but for this exercise, we will assume that we are using an `unsigned bigint`.

So, in theory, we've got this infinitely scalable MySQL table that is defined such as:

- id: `unsigned bigint AUTO_INCREMENT`
- title: `varchar(100)`
- url: `varchar(500)`

The storage requirements for each of these columns are:

- id: 8 bytes
- title: 100 + 1 = 101 bytes
- url: 500 + 2 = 502 bytes
- Row size*: 502 + 101 + 8 = **611 bytes** (Neglecting overhead, table headers, indexes, etc)

Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html

Now, to get the theoretical table size we simply multiply by our *1 trillion* unique URLs:

611 bytes * 1,000,000,000,000 URLs = 611,000,000,000,000 bytes =~ **555.7 terabytes**

So there you have it. 1 trillion URLs times the storage size of the table we defined would take up almost 556 terabytes of data. We would also have to add data for indexes, table overhead, and some other things. Likewise, we could also *subtract* data because for our exercise I assumed each `varchar` column was being maxed out. I hope this helps.

*(Also, just a quick clarification: I know that bigint columns aren't near-infinite, but doing the math is easier when you're not worrying about logistics)*